# How do you change how the active admin search for records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, acts-as-paranoid

I'm working on a Rails 6 application and in the `active-admin` I want to show all the records, including the ones soft-deleted with `paranoia`.

I did that adding `scope :with_deleted, default: true`.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  actions :all, except: [:edit, :new]
  permit_params :body, :user_id

  scope :with_deleted, default: true
end
```

But when I click on the `view` action in the `active-admin` dashboard the soft-deleted record I get a

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Admin::PostController#show
Couldn't find Post with 'id'=2 [WHERE "post"."deleted_at" IS NULL]
```

How can I change the search in the active-admin?

UPDATE: I solve this adding this code to `/admin/posts.rb`

```
  controller do
    def show
      @post = Post.find_by_id(params[:id])
    end

    def scoped_collection
      Post.with_deleted
    end
  end
```

Comment: Have you looked at [active_admin_paranoia](https://github.com/raihan2006i/active_admin_paranoia)?

Comment: Yeah but it didn't work well with friendly_id gem and it hasn't been updated in 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

You can define method `find_resource` on `controller` scope:

```
controller do
  def find_resource
    scoped_collection.findy(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Remeber: This method need return one resource, then add `.first` or `.last` to your query.

In my context I use `findy` and it bring one resource.

See the *Customizing resource retrieval* on
https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html